# my sql db will restart while doing apt-get upgrade/update in ubuntu? please confirm

Tags: grub2

I am planning to install security patches in ubuntu server 12.04 by using appt-get update/upgrade.
Kindly confirm while doing security patch gradation, mysql-db service will get restart?
and also confirm after patches installation, is it recommended to restart the whole server to get affect patch installation.

Answer (score 0):

The packages for MySQL (and MariaDB) from the Ubuntu repositories set up init.d scripts to start a DBMS instance at system boot. When replacing such packages, the pre- and post-installation scripts will stop the DBMS instance started by init.d on upgrade and restart it afterwards.

It is generally recommended to restart software upon upgrade, because a running piece of old software may try to load an incompatible piece (e. g. a dynamic library or data file) of its new version.

If you need your DBMS to keep running, you can lock its packages from upgrade or disable automated upgrades altogether.